# encryption text passed through url not decoding Javascript

Tags: javascript, encryption, url-encoding

I am passing an encrypted string using URL and now I can decrypt it because the encrypted string contains `+` symbol. How to bypass this,

I am using AES encryption in Javascript.

My code is,

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>

window.location.href = "check.php?encr="+encodeURIComponent(CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(80,"qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp"));
```

encryption string is `U2FsdGVkX184sTDp%2BB%2Bgpn07shpb6lqRzqTh4BLOMj4%3D`

Decryption code is,

```
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("<?php echo urldecode($_GET["encr"]); ?>", "qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp");
```

How can i avoid `+` symbol. Is there any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer

encryption,

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>

window.location.href = "check.php?encr="+CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(80,"qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp");
```

decryption,

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>

$q = urlencode($_GET["encr"]);
$q = str_replace("+", "%2B",$q);
$q = urldecode($q);

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt("<?php echo $q; ?>", "qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp");
```

Answer (score 1):

Values in `$_GET` are already URL-decoded. Do not decode them again, that's what's causing you issues. Simply `echo $_GET['encore']` will do.

Note that you should also `json_encode` the value to ensure you're outputting proper Javascript syntax:

```
.decrypt(<?php echo json_encode($_GET['encr']); ?>)
```

Comment: Having said that I'd question the core premise of what you're doing with encryption there, but I'm reserving judgement on that...